# Freeze when update GUI

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an alert box with a title, a label and OK button. Whenever it should pop up, it should re-use the same window, not open a new window.

I receive a dialog event from an external thread. It can receive messages outside of known procedures. I want to call `Show()` every time a message arrives.

[image]

```
public partial class AlertBox : Form
{
    private static AlertBox instance;
    public static AlertBox Instance => instance ?? (instance = new AlertBox());

    private AlertBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AlertBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = "";
        Text = "";
    }

    public void Show(string text, string title)
    {
        Show();
        BringToFront();
        Text = title;
        MessageLabel.Text = text;
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = "";
        Text = "";
        Hide();
    }
}
```

However, when calling `Show(text, title)` as shown:

```
internal class Driver
{
    private readonly AlertBox _alertBox = AlertBox.Instance;
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Receive dialog event.
        _connection.OnDialogReceived += (text, title) =>
        {
            _alertBox.Show(text, title);
        };
    }
}
```

The alert box shows up, sets window title, and freezes. Note that the button has become invisible.

[image]

I have tried to use `Invoke`. It freezes with the exact same result.

```
    public void ShowWithInvoke(string text, string title)
    {
        if (!Created)
        {
            CreateControl();
        }

        if (!IsHandleCreated)
        {
            CreateHandle();
        }

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Show();
            BringToFront();
            Text = title;
        });

        if (!MessageLabel.Created || !MessageLabel.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            MessageLabel.CreateControl();
        }

        MessageLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            MessageLabel.Text = text;
        });
    }
```

Comment: "Whenever it should pop up, it should re-use the same window, not open a new window." - why, exactly? Alert messages are usually shown as modal dialog.

Comment: Where is the OnDialogReceived event being fired from? A background thread perhaps?

Comment: @Nyerguds, it shows some output to the user, and it can send many messages in a short time.

Comment: @HandbagCrab, it is called in a method that is called by an external API. I believe it's another thread.

Comment: I recommend a status bar or something then... or a log window. A window showing just the latest message seems pretty useless. Anyway, have you tried actually running the dialog on a separate thread?

Comment: That's where your problem most likely lies, it's coming from a background thread and is needing to be marshalled to the UI thread. In your invoke code you don't actually create the control within the Invoke so it'll be created on the background thread then the invoke will attempt to access it from the UI thread. That's probably why you're having issues. Of course, it may also be that your background thread is firing the event often and that is causing the hang.

Comment: Calling this from the wrong thread should cause an exception, not a hung UI. And the Invoke should have fixed that. So you probably have more problems. Is the Main window still responsive?

Comment: You want to reuse a form so you need to create one instance of the form and not close it when you exit.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng - the OP is using Hide(), not CLose()

Comment: Hide does not return from the form.  To return from the form without disposing you need to use Close() but set cancel = true.

Comment: "return from the form" is not really a thing. Maybe you were thinking about ShowDialog().

Comment: Please never ever ever do `public new void` - it's going to cause you more grief that you can deal with. Can you not call `override`?

Comment: Instead create `BringToFrontSafely` (etc) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to solve this problem is to decouple the code that sends the alert from the code that displays the alert.

To start with you should create a class that has the sole purpose in life to pass on an update to whatever UI is listening.

```
public class MessageUpdater
{
    public event EventHandler<string> MessageSent;
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        this.MessageSent?.Invoke(this, message);
    }
}
```

It's very simple. It just takes the message and, if there are handlers attached to the event it raises the event.

Now for your `AlertBox` you just accept a `MessageUpdater` instance and update the `Label` whenever the `MessageSent` event is fired.

```
public partial class AlertBox : Form
{
    public AlertBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MessageUpdater _messageUpdater = null;

    public MessageUpdater MessageUpdater
    {
        set
        {
            if (_messageUpdater != null)
            {
                _messageUpdater.MessageSent -= UpdateMessage;
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                _messageUpdater = value;
                _messageUpdater.MessageSent += UpdateMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMessage(object sender, string message)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => this.UpdateMessage(sender, message)));
        }
        else
        {
            this.MessageLabel.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

The two tricky parts here are handling the attachment of a new `MessageUpdater` (and the removal of an existing one) and then marshalling the calls to the UI thread if need be.

The code I created to test this was fairly simple.

```
        var mu = new MessageUpdater();

        var counter = 0;
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((System.Threading.TimerCallback)(x =>
        {
            mu.SendMessage((counter++).ToString());
        }), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

        var ab = new AlertBox();
        ab.MessageUpdater = mu;
        ab.ShowDialog();
```

The tricky part here is the `System.Threading.Timer` that I used to push messages to the `MessageUpdater` *on a non-UI thread* so that the `.ShowDialog` wouldn't freeze up.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put your code along with mine that you are using **after** your existing question?

Comment: In your example move `ab.Show();` into the timer callback. I have updated the question with the current state.

Comment: @Jam - You can't move `ab.Show()` into the timer callback - it's on the wrong thread. You need to call `.Show()` on the UI thread.